# Logic Apps Azure's SQL Connector ReturnCode -3

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that calls a stored procedure to insert a record and update another record in an Azure SQL Managed Instance.

The Logic Apps runs successfully. The SQL Action returns an HTTP 200 (success) but with these outputs:

```
{
  "ResultSets": {},
  "ReturnCode": -3,
  "OutputParameters": {}
}
```

Screenshot of the outputs

[image: 1]

I cannot find anything about negative ReturnCodes while the action succeeded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `ReturnCode` is an integer returned if you specify a return value in the stored procedure. You can refer to this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/xml-and-sql-stored-procedure-in-logic-apps/):

[image]

You can also refer to this [sample](https://www.codit.eu/blog/reliably-receive-sql-data-in-logic-apps/?country_sel=be). In this sample, he specify a value `ROWCOUNT` return.
[image]

Comment: Thanks man. I also saw these blogs, but I couldn't find anything about a negative return code. Do you happen to know anything about the return code "-3"?

Comment: @Mathieu Did you write any code in your stored procedure to return a value ?

Comment: No, only INSERT & UPDATE. However, the SP is using a transaction. I removed it the transaction and now i'm not getting any -3 return codes. So, my guess is that -3 is a code for a sql lock...

Comment: @Mathieu Did you use the sql code like `@@ERROR` function after a Transact-SQL statement ?

Comment: @Mathieu I found another [post](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/using-stored-procedures-sql-server-return-several-results/) which may help you, it says we can use the `@@ERROR` function after a Transact-SQL statement to detect whether an error occurred during the execution of the statement. Show in this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lm7T.png).

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look